# ReferenceError: Объект "google" не определен

Tags: запрос, google-apps-script

Пытаюсь сделать запрос используя [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) . Но скрипт гугл не понимает и не видит объект гугл.

Делал как в справке гугла. Пример кода из справки гугла

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query(DATA_SOURCE_URL);
query.setQuery('select dept, sum(salary) group by dept');
query.send(handleQueryResponse);
```

Скриншот: 
[image: ReferenceError: Объект "google" не определен]

Comment: Видимо надо импортировать библиотеку/модуль google.

Comment: @Эникейщик  А от куда ее брать? Это же вроде должно из коробки работать.  Какой-то проблемный этот гугл.

Answer (score 0):

Построение диаграм - дело клиентских программ. Это не серверная технология, т.к. машинам наши "картинки" ни к чему.

Вероятно, именно из этого подхода следует понимать, что Google Visualization API имеет только клиентскую (браузерную) версию.

Google Apps Script и JavaScript тоже могут добавлять соли - не понятно, где скрипты, а где скрипты. Но следует точно уяснить, что Google Apps Script - язык серверный.

Конечно, весь этот зоопарк можно "поженить" через прослойку "[оператор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F))". Но если это никто не делает, то, вероятно, нет в этом смысла.